# Why javascript not showing value in textfield

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>Testing</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['postbtn'])){
            echo "<script>alert('I am here')</script>";
            echo "<script>document.getElementById('txt_name').value='edit'</script>";
        }
    ?>

    <div id="wrap">
        <form id="data_entry" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
            <div class="rowbox">
                <input type="text" class="textbox" id="txt_name" value="">
            </div>

            <div class="btn">
                <input type="submit" id="postme" name="postbtn">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> I'm new to javascript and php, what I need to know is after submitting the form I can see the alert message "I am here" but I don't see the value that I am posting using the document.getElementById in the textfield for the html form. Why?

Thanks

Comment: For the javascript part: if you got these basics in order, try to dig into JQuery, it will make javascripting a lot easier. Don't forget these are the basics though.

Answer (score 2):

Because the element has not loaded yet, move your script to the end of the body.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['postbtn'])){
        echo "<script>alert('I am here')</script>";
        echo "<script>document.getElementById('txt_name').value='edit';</script>";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```